# How do I assign multiple issues to a project in github

Tags: github, github-issues, github-projects

I cannot find an option for me to bulk select multiple issues and assign them to an project. I can only bulk assign labels and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way I have found...

Projects -> [Your Project] -> + Add cards

(you can change the search filters to find any issues from here)

Click and drag is less intensive than clicking into each issue and assigning it but there should be a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Github has added a way to bulk add issues to Beta Projects now. However, you still cannot bulk add issues to non-Beta Projects.

[image: Github search issues screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible by doing the following:

1. Navigate to the repository which has issues you want to add to a project.
2. Search for `-project:<OWNER>/<PROJECT_ID> is:issue is:open`.
3. Click the topmost "select all issues" checkbox to have all viewed issues selected.
4. Click the "Projects" dropdown menu and select the projects you want the selected issues moved to.
5. Click outside of the dropdown to assign the issues to the selected project.
6. Wait until the process completes.
7. Refresh the page and repeated from step 3 until all issues have been moved to the selected project and the search returns an empty list.

The search string `-project:<OWNER>/<PROJECT_ID>` means "find all issues that is not assigned to the specified project" and will look like `-project:github/4247` for [all issues in the `github/docs` repository not assigned](https://github.com/github/docs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+-project%3Agithub%2F4247+) to the [GitHub Public Roadmap project](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247).